# Stored array into Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, arrays

I have stored a 2d array in a MySql db

```
[["c0"]["33925"],["c1"]["39280"],["c2"]["34079"],["c3"]["34091"],["c4"]["34108"]]
```

I want to convert this into a javascript array.

I am using a php page to get the array using `xmlhttp.responseText`;

which gets the array, but I can't do anything with it;

```
var layoutArray = new Array();   
layoutArray = xmlhttp.responseText;    
alert(layoutArray[0][0]);
```

Comment: You could use `eval` - I predict the next comments may be "eval is evil!"

Comment: @Jeff As long as you know what you're doing, and none of the data *ever* originated from user input, you should be ok. (Note the emphasis on "ever")

Comment: @lc - thats exactly the reason I proposed eval in this situation. :)

Comment: Why are you storing an array as string at all? Just store a JSON string and you don't need to `eval()` the string.

Comment: eval is evil :) but its only evil, if you can't trust what you are eval'ing.

Comment: `[["c0"]["33925"],["c1"]["39280"],["c2"]["34079"],["c3"]["34091"],["c4"]["34108"]]` doesn't like useful JSON. How is it supposed to behave?

Answer (score 2):

Try to eval the array because you are getting a string back:

```
layoutArray = eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

In general you should avoid the use of `eval` especially if the data you are running `eval` on is coming from your users. However if only you can tamper with this value, then `eval` is safe.

Comment: A good idea would be mentioning why eval is safe in this situation :)

Answer (score 0):

i would store the array as a JSON string like feeela said.

```
var layoutArray = {"c0":"33925","c1":"39280","c2":"34079","c3":"34091","c4":"34108"}

for (key in layoutArray){
     console.log(layoutArray[key])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `serialize` before putting it into the database and `unserialize` when extracting it. You'll have your json structure without using eval on the clientside.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending back the result using a PHP script, and "must" store the data as an array instead of JSON to begin with, I would just [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the array and return that:

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0cd737aeec75b663ab308f5f25bdae1f508b054)

```
$array = array("1" => "PHP code tester Sandbox Online",  
          "foo" => "bar", 5 , 5 => 89009, 
          "case" => "Random Stuff");

echo json_encode($array)
```